# Can one legally take the derivative of a derivative?

Tags: calculus

Let $$ f(n,x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \cos(x) =  \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \: \cos(x) - \sin(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \: \sin(x)$$

Can one take the derivative with respect to $n$ so that one has $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial n} f(n,x) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \: \cos(x) + \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \: \sin(x) \right) $$

Is this just nonsense?

Comment: There is such a thing as fractional derivatives, but it is non-trivial.  However, generally speaking the integers can't be treated like real numbers when it comes to things involving limits (like derivatives).  But, the answer below from Kenny Lau gives a workaround, though this changes the meaning of $n$ and you can no longer write $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is important to understand that functions, at least in rigorous mathematics, require a domain and a codomain, a fact which the Leibniz notation unfortuantely obscures.

A priori, your $f$ is a function $\Bbb N \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, so you can't take partial derivative w.r.t. the first variable.

However, your formula showed that you can **extend** $f$ "naturally" to become a function $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and now you can  take partial derivative w.r.t. the first variable.

Now it is very very important to note that the extended function is not the same as $f$, because they have different domains; however, not every situation requires a separate notation like $\overline{f}$ for the extended function, so sometimes "abuse of notation" allows us to re-use the same variable $f$ for the extended function, when the context is clear enough.

So yes, after you extended the function $f$ using the formula, then you can take partial derivative.

Comment: Very clear and concise! Thank you

Comment: Given the title of the question, it should be perhaps emphasized that the extension function is no longer a derivative of $f$, but just a function in two variables where the first one was extended from naturals to reals. Otherwise put, $\frac{\partial}{\partial n} f(n,x)$ can be legitimized by extension, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial n} f^{(n)}(x)$ cannot.

Comment: I have seen before that there is some theory of *fractional* derivatives---for $n$ rational, does the fractional derivative agree with simply generalizing the OP's formula in the "obvious" way?